# What are the arguments for xlDialogChartSourceData?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the xlDialogChartSourceData dialog; there are probably 30 arguments of the method " Show", however, the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Controls-DialogBoxes-Forms/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists page does not show which ones are.

This code shows the dialogbox, but I want to mark or unmark some of the values in the right or left list.

```
Sub proDiaAktualisieren()

  Dim objDiagramm

  Diagrammmuster1.Activate

  For Each objDiagramm In Diagrammmuster1.ChartObjects
    objDiagramm.Activate
    With ActiveChart
      Application.Dialogs(xlDialogChartSourceData).Show
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

What are the Arguments of ".Show", and what do they control in the dialog?

Comment: What makes you think it does have arguments?

Comment: This Tooltip in the Editor:

Comment: If you type a blank after .Show a list of 30 Arguments (arg1 - arg30) appears .

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting that.  That is the argument list for `Dialogs.Show`.  It does not mean that there *are* 30 arguments, just that that is how many are supported.  The arguments are shown on the page you linked to above and in this case, there are none.

Comment: Oh thx, I was in fear of this answer;-)  Now, I have to change the values in the dialogs of 18 Charts by Hand;-(